# I have an error WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: php, wpdb

Hello im new to WPDB and this is my error

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''questions' ORDER by id DESC' at line 1]
```

SELECT * from 'questions' ORDER by id DESC

This is my code

```
//Get data from Table
global $wpdb;
$vragen = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * from %s ORDER by id DESC", 'questions'), 
    ARRAY_A
);
```

please halp

Comment: Does the error go away if you change `ORDER by` to `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here you are passing `table name` as a placeholder in prepare statement. Which is not allowed. You can directly add the table name in your query without quotes.
Your query do not have any placeholder and arguments. So No need for prepare statement.

Try following code.

```
global $wpdb;
$vragen = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from questions ORDER BY id DESC", 
    ARRAY_A
);
```

Comment: it works thanks

Comment: @ShadyMorsi . If this answers your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer. It will helps others find it as resolved.